# Why can't my Firefox load CNN.com properly?

Tags: firefox, images

I've noticed that if I load CNN.com in Firefox, the images aren't loading. The page looks like this:

[image]

If I view the same page in Internet Explorer it looks fine. Friends I've asked who use Firefox for Windows say they have no problem seeing the images on CNN. I'm having no trouble viewing any other page.

I've already tried the following remedies:

1. Restart browser.
2. Restart machine.
3. Clear private data (Cache, Cookies, Offline Website Data, Authenticated Sessions).
4. Disabling all add-ons and restarting browser.
5. Reinstalling browser.
6. Running an A-Squared Free scan.

None of these made any difference whatsoever.

I am running Firefox 3.5.3. My operating system is Windows XP Professional SP3.

**Questions:**

1. If you are running Firefox on a Windows machine, how does CNN look to you?
2. Any other ideas of what I could try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you turned image loading off, or you selected an option like "load images from originating site only".

Comment: You got it! I had the general option "Load Images Automatically" turned *on*, but for some reason, there was exception in there for CNN. I have no memory of putting that there, but I guess I must have at some point. Anyway, thanks. It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Try a "hard reload":

Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: That's a really good idea. I don't think it would have made any difference for this particular problem, but it's something I know will come in handy in other situations.

Comment: Indeed, on the screenshot it looked like the CSS had been messed up. A reload of the CSS file could have solved it in that case.